# Failed to save data into postgres database using sequelize.js, but system return column multiple times

Tags: reactjs, express, sequelize.js

While trying to save data into `postgres` database using sequelize `BlogModel.create()` system failed to save the data into table and server is returning columns `createdat, updatedat,` multiple times in console. ( please see below ).  In the scheme I have added the column only once, can someone advise on this issue here ?

Executing (default): INSERT INTO "userBlogs" ("id","email","blogdetails","tags","createdat","updatedat","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7) RETURNING "id","email","blogdetails","tags","createdat","updatedat","createdAt","updatedAt";

//userBlogs.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const userBlogs = sequelize.define('userBlogs', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
            allowNull: false
        },
        blogdetails: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: false
        },
        tags: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
            allowNull: false
        },
        createdat: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW
        },
        updatedat: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW
        }
    }, {
        timestamps: true,
        tableName: 'userBlogs'
    });

    return userBlogs;
};
```

//server.js

```
const usersBlogSchema = require('./modals/userBlogs');
  const BlogModel = usersBlogSchema(sequelize, DataTypes);


 app.post('/service/createblogs', async (req, res, next)=> {

    try {
      const userEmail = req.body.email;
      const blogDetails = req.body.blogValue;
      const tags = req.body.tagValue;

      if (Object.keys(req.body).length === 0) {
        res.status(403).json({ fail: "Invalid blog request or blog request is blank !" });
      } else {
      var requestData = {email:userEmail, blogdetails:blogDetails, tags:tags  };
      const createBlogRequest = await BlogModel.create(requestData);
       res.status(200).json({ success: true });
      }
    } catch (e) {
     console.log(e)
     return next(e);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning *createdAt* and *updatedAt* multiple times because you have added columns (createdAt and updatedAt )and also *timestamps:true* ,
timestamps also adds these both columns
use either columns or timestamps

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const userBlogs = sequelize.define('userBlogs', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
            allowNull: false
        },
        blogdetails: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: false
        },
        tags: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
            allowNull: false
        },
    }, {
        timestamps: true,
        tableName: 'userBlogs'
    });

    return userBlogs;
};
```

Comment: Thank you Qamar, appreciate your help !. I didn't realize that , solved the problem. Upvoted and accepted !

Comment: Awesome reply !